# Mounting a Box folder to a docker container in windows

Tags: docker, mounted-volumes

Im able to mount a local folder into my docker container, no problem. The issue arises when I try mounting a Box folder, I assume that Docker doesn´t have the Box permissions and thats why I am not able to mount it.

I have tried mounting it as any other folder --> fails

Mounting the folder as a network drive first in my local system and then mounting that drive into the container (works with any local folder) --> fails for the Box folder.

Any idea as how to go about this?